# Python: Appending elements to list of a class

Tags: python, list, class, attributes

I have a class that looks like this

```
class Someclass(something):
    name = "SomeClass"
    field=[XShortField("Field", 0x1000)]
```

This class is used by another function, but before it is used i would like to append elements to the field, like

```
if option == 0: #nothing is added
   pass 
elif option == 1: #one element is added
   SomeClass.field.append(XShortField("Field"+str(option), 0x2000))
elif option == 2: #two elements are added
#and so on
```

But it seems I can't do it like that. Is there a special way to access a classes attributes?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: You're missing a bracket at the end of that line, is that in your original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a subclass here:

```
class Someclass1(Someclass):
    field = Someclass.field + [XShortField("Field"+str(option), 0x2000]

s_class = Someclass
if option == 0: #nothing is added
    pass
elif option == 1: #one element is added
    s_class = Someclass1
elif option == 2: #two elements are added
    [...]
    #and so on
```

It depends on your context, but, for example, if you're writing a dissector for Scapy, that's probably a good way to do that ;-)

In the specific case of Scapy protocols, you can have a look at the `ConditionalField()` that might be a good solution to your problem (see [Scapy source code](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src/8290505df9ecbe4e4061f116088009dcc74dc5dc/scapy/fields.py?at=default#cl-129) for more information).

Comment: Thank you, that looks like what i needed. I'll try that. But what is a ConditionalField() ? I can't find much about it.